# Extract the first occurence of the digits and the last word of filename

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have a list of file names like this,

```
filenames = ['122 CHC Sep 2017.xlsx', '124 CHC Sep 2017 RFK.xlsx', '124 CHC Sep 2018 Trc.xlsx']
```

I want the first occurrence of digits and the last word.

My output needed like this,

```
['122', '124 RFK', '124 Trc']
```

I tried the following,

```
regex = re.compile(r'^\D*(\d+)([a-zA-Z]+)\.[a-zA-Z]+$') 
[regex.findall(x) for x in filenames]
```

I am getting

```
[['122'],['124'], ['124']]
```

I tried this,

```
regex = re.compile(r'^\D*(\d+).*?([a-zA-Z]+)\.[a-zA-Z]+$')
[regex.findall(x) for x in filenames]
```

I am getting,

```
[[], ['124', 'RFK'], ['124', 'Trc']]
```

This time I am not getting `122`.

How can I change my code? Any suggestions would be great!

(Note: If there is a way to capitalize all alphabets and then do the regex, that would be awesome)

Comment: Try `re.sub(r'^\D*(\d+)(?:.*?(\s*[a-zA-Z]+)|.*)\.[a-zA-Z]+$', r'\1\2', x)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  Nice! That worked although it returns as a tuple. Would you mind posting it as answer with some explanation. I really would like to know what is happening under the hood. I have been following the python docs, did not help much :(

Comment: do you know about http://regex101.com , switch to python mode, paste demo text & pattern (without r' and ')  and read the textual explanation on site?

Comment: @PatrickArtner Cool, that seems like a nice resource. I haven't used it before. I'll explore it for sure!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^\D*(\d+)(?:.*?(\s*[a-zA-Z]+)|.*)\.[a-zA-Z]+$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EZclOK/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\D*` - 0+ non-digits
- `(\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits
- `(?:.*?(\s*[a-zA-Z]+)|.*)` - either of the two alternatives:

  - `.*?(\s*[a-zA-Z]+)` - any 0+ chars, as few as possible followed with a Group 1 capturing 0+ whitespaces and 1+ letters
  - `|` - or
  - `.*` - any 0+ chars, as many as possible
- `\.` - a dot
  -`[a-zA-Z]+` - 1+ letters
- `$` - end of string.

Below is the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Ry0Uzl):

```
import re
filenames = ['122 CHC Sep 2017.xlsx', '124 CHC Sep 2017 RFK.xlsx', '124 CHC Sep 2018 Trc.xlsx']
rx = re.compile(r'^\D*(\d+)(?:.*?(\s*[a-zA-Z]+)|.*)\.[a-zA-Z]+$')
print([rx.sub(r'\1\2', x) for x in filenames])
# => ['122', '124 RFK', '124 Trc']
```

Comment: Perfect! Much appreciated! Gotta love `python` more and more!